# Appending data to the specific table cell - jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some issue with jQuery TimeTable, I have created a table like

Monday
            
            
                Tuesday
            
            ...... upto saturday
            ......

From and To are two dropdown lists, with this am allocatting the timings for these days,like

```
    var totalCol += 1;
$("#tabTimetable > tbody > tr:gt(0)").append("<td class='timetableslot " + totalCol + "' onclick='selTimeSlot(this);'></td>");
```

If I click a particular cell it will ask the Section Name and StaffIncharge in a textbox, here StaffInCharge is a autocomplete box, in the selected item event am binding the data in that particular cell. I can get the CurrentRow and CurrentColumn like

```
currentCol = $(objCol).parent().children().index($(objCol));
currentRow = $(objCol).parent().parent().children().index($(objCol).parent());
```

and I have the data to be displayed as

```
var data = "<div class='timetableslotselected'><table width='100%'><tr><td align='right'><div class='close16' onclick='removeItem(" + timetable[i].Row + "," + timetable[i].Col + ",event)' /></td></tr></table><div><table><tr><td><img src='" + timetable[i].Photo + "' width='32px' height='32px'/></td><td>" + timetable[i].Name + " ( " + timetable[i].ItemName + " )</td></tr></table></div></div> ";
```

I need to bind this "data" to that particular cell...I dunno how to do this...is it possible to bind like

```
$("#tabTimetable")[currentRow][currentCol].append(data);
```

Comment: All your stuff before the last sentence are irrelevent, you should delete them. the only thing that you ask is how to "Append data to the specific table cell", all those TimeTable doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#tabTimetable tr:eq([currentRow]) td:eq([currentCol])").append(data);
```

eq() selectors are indexed from 0

Comment: which lines u r asking me to delete

Comment: The only last 2 lines are relevant, that you wnat to append data to specific table cell, you don't need to write about the content of that table, it doesn't matter. what matter is that you have 2 indexes `currentRow` an `currentCol` and want to append data to cell with that indexes.

Comment: The question should be "I have two indexes currentRow and currentCol how to access specific cell with this indexes" and that's it, the rest is irrelevant.